# How do I efficiently combine remote files (AWS S3) + locally generated pdf files as .zip files in node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, amazon-s3, graphql, amazon-cloudfront

I am building an application where media files and pdf certificates can be downloaded by users.

The media files are stored in AWS S3 buckets and are retrieved using CloudFront URLs, while the certificates are to be generated on the fly by the backend node.js **GraphQL** API server running on **Heroku**.

What would be the best way to fetch the required media files, generate the certificate, add the files and certificates to an archive (`zip`), then deliver the archive to the frontend.

My first thought is to:

- client request ---
- download media
- generate pdf
- compress and save archive (single use only, no longer necessary after download)
- server response (send link to the client)

Is there a way to make this more efficient? I don't want to tie down server resources processing files and would like to avoid saving the zip files on the server. Are there other tools or services that I can delegate that task to?

Comment: The ZIP file format is streamable.  You can compress objects as they are downloaded by your server, and stream this ZIP output to the client at the same time.

Comment: @Brad won't  that lead to bottlenecks on the server when many clients initiate multiple downloads?

Comment: Certainly less bottlenecks than doing the same thing, but with a disk read/write in the middle.